# What does this "setState" do in the code? Should not it return a blank inititalState

Tags: reactjs

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.initialState = {
      name: "",
      job: ""
    };

    this.state = this.initialState;
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  submitForm = () => {
    this.props.handleSubmit(this.state);
    this.setState(this.initialState);
  };
```

The code works okay. I just wonder what the "setState" function does
In my perspective, after users submitting a form, it should empty the inititalState for further use. But after "handleChange", the initalState contains data. So why we have to reassign?

Answer (score 3):

When you write `this.state = this.initialState;`, you set `this.state` to point to the same object that `this.initialState` points to, rather than creating a new object that is identical to `this.initialState`. So when the state is later changed, `this.initialState` is also changed. This is why your component still has non-empty data in its state even after calling `this.setState(this.initialState);`.

You can fix this by setting `this.state` equal to a *copy* of `this.initialState`, like this:

```
this.state = { ...this.initialState };
```

Note that things get a bit more complicated for nested objects (and arrays) where you'll need to do a deep copy of the object/array, but this solution works in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! I have one more question: in the "submitForm" method, after users submitting the form data, the firm should return blank right? Then users can submit new data through the firm. My code actually work but I just do not understand what is the function of "this.setState(this.initialState)"

Comment: Really appreciate for the answer!

Comment: @Rieder it seems that the point of `this.setState(this.initialState)` is to clear the form data. This might be useful if you have a button like "Create and Add Another" where you would send off your form data like a normal submit, but then stay on the same page but clear the existing form data. Does that help answer that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to confuse you more than you need to but I wanted to add some gotcha information on the above answer.

Like @Henry Woody stated `this.state = { ...this.initialState };`
 works fine in your case, but if your React state includes arrays or nested objects ([Anything passed through reference](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)), you will need to deep clone your object in order to get rid of the nested reference therefore avoiding mutating them inadvertently:

From [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript):

```
this.state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialState));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Your document is really helpful! Thumbs Up!